# Email to my Google Apps address sometimes bounces

Tags: email, google-apps, email-bounces

I have my domain email hosted on Google Apps, the free version. The problem is that occasionally/frequently, emails sent to me bounce. Someone forwarded me the bounce message:

```
Delivery to the following recipient failed permanently:

 steven@vanesoftware.com

Technical details of permanent failure:
Google tried to deliver your message, but it was rejected by the recipient domain. We
recommend contacting the other email provider for further information about the cause of 
this error. The error that the other server returned was: 554 554 5.7.1 
<steven@vanesoftware.com>: Recipient address rejected: Access denied (state 13).
```

My domain is hosted on hover.com, here's a screenshot of my DNS entries:

[image: DNS screenshot]

What am I doing wrong, or how can I troubleshoot this? Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your top level domain cannot have a CNAME record. Remove the @ CNAME record and create an A record pointing to the IP address of pl1705.pairlitesite.com or, if your DNS host has one, use a WebHop / HTTP redirect.

Jay

Comment: Thanks. Can you help me understand how this causes email bounces?

Comment: The CNAME record overrides the MX records so mail servers sending to your email addresses wind up talking to pl1705.pairlitesite.com instead of aspmx.l.google.com. A good explanation of the behavior is offered at: http://email-museum.com/2008/09/08/why-you-shouldnt-mix-cname-and-mx/